# Organizing div elements

Tags: html, css, position

I want to organize my three div elements so that the look like in the picture beliow. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Show us your html and css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is some basic code

```css
/* for demo purposes */
html, body, #container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

/* main container */
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#red {
  height: 50%;
  background:red;
}

#green { 
  background:green; height: 50%;
}

#yellow {
  background:yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  /* vertical centering */
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  /* horizontal centering */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="red">Top</div>
  <div id="green">Bottom</div>
  <div id="yellow">Middle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way that I can make this yellow element look good in mobile devices?

Maybe using media queries?

Answer (score 3):

Here you have one option how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/x91qdxxh/

HTML:

CSS:

```
.full {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.upper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.lower {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: -150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```